# Download of Linux packages using yum utility over a Python script fails

Tags: linux, python-2.7, yum

I am looking to ONLY download multiple packages (600 plus) using the yum utility through a Python script.

Execution of the script fails. How can I fix this?

Following is the Python script used

```
# cat package-download.py
import os

filename="test.txt"
file=open(filename,"r")
for i in file:
        os.system("/usr/bin/yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/root/packages-download" +i)
```

Below is the file containing information about the packages

```
#cat test.txt
nfs-utils
```

Execution of the script reports the following error:

```
]# python package-download.py
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Error: Need to pass a list of pkgs to install
 Mini usage:

install PACKAGE...

Install a package or packages on your system

aliases: install-n, install-na, install-nevra
```

The yum utility works fine outside the Python script:

```
# yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/root/packages-download  nfs-utils
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nfs-utils.ppc64 1:1.3.0-0.54.el7 will be installed
+++++++++++++ output truncated++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Does your test.txt file contain only one package name or multiple?and if multiple, How are they separated?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a space in the command line:

```
        os.system("/usr/bin/yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/root/packages-download " +i)
                                                                                            ^ here
```

It's better to use the `subprocess` module, which doesn't have trouble with escaping and such:

```
        subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/yum', 'install', '--downloadonly', '--downloaddir=/root/packages-download', i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
os.system("/usr/bin/yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/root/packages-download" +i)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
#---------------------------------------------contains no space between download" + i
```

and as result it would return `--downloaddir=/root/packages-downloadnfs-utils` instead of `--downloaddir=/root/packages-download nfs-utils`

Try the following code, which has space between package name and argument, and it also checks for empty string as package name:-

```
import os

filename="test.txt"  
file=open(filename,"r")
for i in file:
    packageName = i.strip()
    if packageName:
        print packageName
        os.system("/usr/bin/yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/root/packages-download " +packageName)
```

However, I would still advice to use `subprocess` instead of `os`.